# Analyzing cumbersome information

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I am creating an interactive gradebook environment for my friends and I. So far I have been able to use my script, download my grades, & filter what information is important. My script goes as follows.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#   Connect to D2L
s = requests.Session()
payload = {
    'd2l_referrer': '',
    'target': '/d2l/lp/ouHome/loginHome.d2l?isMobile=1',
    'loginPath': '/d2l/m/login',
    'userName': 'USERNAME',
    'password': 'PASSWORD'
}
r = s.post('http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l', data=payload)
status = r.status_code
if status == 200:
    print "Connection Successful"
else:
    print "Unable to connect"

#   Grade Collection
print "     Getting CLASS grades..."
page = s.get("GRADEBOOK URL")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
grade = BeautifulSoup(str(soup.find_all('label')))
for strings in grade.stripped_strings:
    if "/" in strings:
        print strings
print "Complete"
```

The script returns:

```
Connection Successful
     Getting CLASS grades...
50 / 50
40 / 50
40 / 50
45 / 50
50 / 50
Complete
```

At this point, I want the program to total the numbers on either side of the "/" and divide the totals, thus giving an "average". Ex. `((50+40+40+45+50)/(50+50+50+50+50)) = 0.9` or (`90%`).

Comment: Your title reads like a spam email.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? What have you tried to extract the numbers so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to extract the grade information; you didn't specify what the numbers mean, so I'll guess they are called `passed` and `total`:

```
passed = totals = 0

for strings in grade.stripped_strings:
    if "/" in strings:
        print strings
        pass_, total = map(float, strings.split('/'))
        passed += pass_
        totals += total

print "The average is: {:.1%}".format(passed / totals)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lines = '''\
... 50 / 50
... 40 / 50
... 40 / 50
... 45 / 50
... 50 / 50
... '''
>>> for strings in lines.splitlines():
...     if "/" in strings:
...         print strings
...         pass_, total = map(float, strings.split('/'))
...         passed += pass_
...         totals += total
... 
50 / 50
40 / 50
40 / 50
45 / 50
50 / 50
>>> print "The average is: {:.1%}".format(passed / totals)
The average is: 90.0%
```

The `.1%` format instruction formats a floating point number as a percentage with 1 decimal point (multiplying by 100 and adding the `%` character).